# How to wrap in Listbox

Tags: python

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Help")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

help_message = 'This is the help menu. Please scroll through the menu to find the answer to your question'

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
listbox.insert(END, help_message)

listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

When I run this code, the text goes past the boundary of the listbox. Is there a parameter that I can add to this so that I can get the text to wrap to the next line. I don't care if part of a word is cut off or not. I tried to make the listbox bigger but still the text doesn't wrap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Text` widget instead of `Listbox`. `Text` widget has `wrap` option. (NONE, CHAR, WORD)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Help")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

help_message = 'This is the help menu. Please scroll through the menu to find the answer to your question'

txt = Text(root, wrap=WORD) # wrap=CHAR, wrap=NONE
txt.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
txt.insert(END, help_message)

txt.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)

mainloop()
```